# Laravel Eloquent - where created_at is X days ago

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an array of days that I want to check against for trials ending in Laravel Spark:

```
$trialIntervals = [10, 5, 3, 1, 0];
```

I fetch all teams and then check if their trial_ends_at date one of the intervals using diffInDays:

```
$daysTillTrialEnds = Carbon::parse($team->trial_ends_at)->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
```

I then check if this value is already an existing result in the database and in the intervals:

```
if ( in_array($daysTillTrialEnds, $trialIntervals) && !TrialEndingNotification::where('team_id', $team->id)->where('days_notified_at', $daysTillTrialEnds)->count() ) {

   // not yet been added to db

}
```

I have a field called 'days_notified_at' that I am using the check if I have already added the row and notified the customer. However that field is never used again and I would rather reference the created_at date and remove the field.

My question is how I essentially do this:

```
->where(Carbon::parse('created_at')->diffInDays(Carbon::now()), $daysTillTrialEnds)
```

Without getting this error:

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (created_at) at position 0 (c): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

The aim is that the where will only show rows that have a created_at date that is X days ago.

Comment: maybe because in the where function "->where()" the first arguments is the field name, so Carbon::parse as first arguments in where has not sense

Comment: Laravel has a `whereDate()` function that will probably help you a lot in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use WhereRaw

```
->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d'))'), $daysTillTrialEnds)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
->where(Carbon::parse('created_at')->diffInDays(Carbon::now()), $daysTillTrialEnds)
```

to should be like

```
->where(Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->diffInDays(Carbon::now()), $daysTillTrialEnds)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create scope in model like this :

```
public function scopeActive($query)
{
    return $query->whereDate('created_at' , '=', Carbon::today()->subDays( 2 ));

}
```

after that call scope in controller :

```
    $post = Post::active()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
$dayAgo = 6 // where here there is your calculation for now How many days
$dayToCheck = Carbon::now()->subDays($dayAgo);
$model->whereDate("created_at", =, $dayToCheck);
```

Comment: This will works per 1 second in day, because `created_at` is timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel will automatically turn the "created_at" into a carbon object so you don't have to parse it.

```
`$items->where('created_at')->diffInDays(Carbon::now(), $daysTillTrialEnds)'
```

Should work for you